# Subtraction in verilog

Tags: verilog, subtraction

I am using code like this:

```
reg [16:0] result;
reg gradient;

result = (gradient) ? (result+1) : (result-1);
```

My problem is at 
`result = 7` and `gradient = 0`. Then I get `result = 4`.

It doesnt appear at `result = 8` and `gradient = 1 or 0` and any other combination. But at `result = 13` and `gradient = 1` to `result = 18`.

**Binary notation**

```
7-1 = 0111 - 0001 = 0110 = 6
7-1 = 0111 - 0001 = 0010 = 4

13+1 = 1101 + 0001 =   1110 = 14
13+1 = 1101 + 0001 = 1 0010 = 18
```

Anybody has an idea why this strange behavior comes up?
I tried to eliminate all other code lines dealing with result and gradient for more than needed.

Comment: To fully analyze why you are getting the results that youre getting, you need to supply the full code that contains the `result = (gradient) ? (result+1) : (result-1);` line. By itself, I cant tell why you are getting 4 from 7.

Comment: Please modify left-hand side `result` in `result = (gradient) ? (result+1) : (result-1);` to any other variable and check the output.

Answer (score 1):

The strange behaviour comes from a combinational loop you have created in your code. You have a 17 bit two channel multiplexer which outputs the value `gradient`, which in turn is derived to both an incrementer and a decrementer, whose outputs go to the inputs of the multiplexer. This causes `gradient` to change its value very fast, with only the delay introduced by the combinational circuit that has been inferred. In a simulation, with no delays, the output of such combinational loops is undetermined.

Either you use another variable to hold the output of the multiplexer...

```
reg [16:0] result, result2;
reg gradient;

always @* begin
  result2 = (gradient) ? (result+1) : (result-1);
end
```

Or you use a clocked register to change its value on each clock cycle (which is most probably what you were looking for), I presume:

```
reg [16:0] result;
reg gradient;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  result <= (gradient) ? (result+1) : (result-1);
end
```